# How to apply Android settings to all projects

Tags: android, gradle

I have many projects that are subprojects of one project, and I was wondering, given that they all have, for example, the same `minSdkVersion`, if I could write in the main project's `build.gradle` something like this:

```
subprojects {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 20
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
}
```

I tried that and when I build the projects it outputs this error:

```
Error:(34, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
subprojects{
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 20
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover do you have a settings.gradle file that reference subprojects to build? If not you must create one. For more information [check this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).